# InflateException: Binary XML file line #60: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView

Tags: android

I keep on receiving this error and i don't know where this error occurs this the xml file

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

And here it is the log cat

```
04-17 02:19:25.556: W/dalvikvm(731): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sbn.project.gp/sbn.project.gp.Mainevent}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #60: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #60: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at sbn.project.gp.Mainevent.onCreate(Mainevent.java:27)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  ... 11 more
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:238)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  ... 21 more
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:282)
04-17 02:19:25.586: E/AndroidRuntime(731):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:255)
```

And here it is the android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tt.pp.ss"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SbnActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity

            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="tt.pp.ss.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Db"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="tt.pp.ss.DB" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".View"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="tt.pp.ss.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name=".Mainevent"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="tt.pp.ss.MAINEVENT" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Signup"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="tt.pp.ss.SIGNUP" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any help i have spent more than 5 hours and i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.
```

Are you using a MapActivity?

Comment: I am dealing with several classes.The class that i used the MapViews from it i extend it from Mapactivity,but now i want to navigate to other normal Activity and i got that error

Comment: @KhaledMohamed Double-check that setContentView on your new Activity is pointing to the right XML file - my best guess is that you have the maps layout left in there from a copy/paste

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem before and solved it by the following 2 steps:

1) Put the following line in the application (important) element of AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

2) extend **MapActivity** instead of **Activity**.